# How to populate UIpickerView with array after changing its text colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I want to populate my picker view after customising its text. When I could populate it with array I'm not able to change it text colour. I've searched everywhere and I find both separate  either it they have changed the text colour or populated it with array. The below is my code what I've tried.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.CityList count];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    if (row == 0) 
    {
        label.text = self.CityList[0];
    }
    else if (row == 1) 
    {
        label.text = self.CityList[1];
    }
    else if (row == 2) 
    {
        label.text = self.CityList[2];
    }
    else if (row == 3) 
    {
        label.text = self.CityList[3];
    }
    else if (row == 4) 
    {
        label.text = self.CityList[4];
    }
    else if (row == 5) 
    {
        label.text = self.CityList[5];
    }
    return label;
}
```

this code actually works fine but when I have too many in my array it is definitely not efficient to implement it this way. please suggest me an efficient method.

Comment: What is your real question?

Comment: Why are you writing this much, instead of this
label.text = self.CityList[row];

Comment: The above code gives me a way to customise the picker view but i'm not able to populate it with an array by doing so. I've to assign for every row individually…. :(

Comment: Ive tried that but it didn't work..:(

Comment: see refeal's answer to reuse your label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method like this:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
    //Check if the current view requested is a reused one, If not then create a new one
    if (!label)
    {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    }

    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    //Assign the text of the label to the NSString at the index of "row" from your data array
    label.text = self.CityList[row];

    return label;
}
```

Comment: This will have problems I think if there are more than one components per row as the label is being given the full width of the pickerview. But then, reviewing the OP, it did state one component, so I guess this works.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it I found out where I was going wrong not able to assign using array directly. I had assigned my array property to weak. It works just fine after I changed it to strong…;)

Comment: Of corse you need to have your array as Strong and not Weak :)
And make sure you write the method pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: Correctly as I wrote to you.